Are there any diacritics to help foreigners know how to pronounce "ew" in English?
I had a foreigner tell me she bought a sewing machine once, but she pronounced it in a way that borrowed how "ew" is pronounced in "few".  After I figure out what she was saying and corrected her, she asked me how she was supposed to know.
All 3 words "new", "few", and "sew" have endings that are pronounced differently.  There is nothing inherently complicated here when the words are so small.
Are there any diacritics or other guides to help foreigners know how to pronounce "ew" in new, few, and sew correctly, similar to how daearises work for consecutive, non-diphthong vowels?

English doesn't use diacritics.  The few words that have diaresis are borrowed from other languages, and the diaresis is optional-  Sometimes the foreign diacritic is kept by some writers when a word is borrowed. By the way, "few" and "new" have the same sound for "ew", don't they? "sew" is just a weird exception.

@JamesK In BrE generally yes, in AmE generally no.

I speak RP, and to me the -ew parts of new and few are identical.

@JamesK, many Americans pronounce new and knew (homophones) with the same vowel as shoe and shoo.

And while we’re on the -ew words, I don’t know of anyone for whom flew and flue use the vowel in British new (nyoo) rather than the vowel in shoo.

@PaulTanenbaum - you don't know any Welsh people then?

For some Americans, "news" is palatalized, like gnocchi, to rhyme with "fuse" or "spews" and others pronounce  "news" to rhyme with "booze" or "whose".

Very strange.  I've lived in New York, New England and the American southeast, and work with people globally and primarily with English as second language and haven't heard anyone pronounce few (fyoo) and new (noo) with the same ew sound.  I guess its not as common as i thought.

Really, @MichaelHarvey? So in visiting our son during his semester at Swansea University we flju: into Heathrow? I failed to pick that up in Abertawe.

@PaulTanenbaum I've heard it a lot in South Wales speech, espcially Cardiff. A colleague in Newport called Lewis said his name that way, and 'suit' as well.

@MichaelHarvey, sjut doesn’t surprise me. (But I guess we’re wandering afield from the OP’s question.)

American elementary students generally about 'long' and 'short' vowels and write them with a simplified version of the American Heritage Dictionary phonetic guide; this lesson plan (no affiliation, though i can't recommend it since it doesn't seem good) is roughly what I was taught. So other than IPA, you might write "sew is pronounced sōw, like 'grow'".

Sew (/soʊ/) is just "one of those words." There are no other words that share its pattern; it just has to be memorized.
The /u:/ and /ju:/ words are kind of all over the place and can differ between dialects. The good news is that you're unlikely to be misunderstood if you get one of them wrong. You could annotate it with a superscript j (the IPA letter "yod"), as this sound is sometimes transcribed: fʲew.
This person was unlucky with "sew", but no amount of rules and logic will keep you from running into pronunciation booby traps in English.
